# RadioButtons and text invisible on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-radiogroup

I'm using Android Studio and I have an app with a radio group of 4 buttons in my project, wich are used to pick an answer from my database. The buttons are invisible on the device but can still click them as they show up a green color when clicked. Also the text is not showing for each answer but the question text in the `textview` above the radio buttons is showing! Very confusing. Has anyone ran into this issue and know how to resolve it? Here's a copy of my xml layout

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" 
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/group1">

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:id="@+id/question"/>

            <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer1"
                />

            <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer2"
                />

            <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer3"
                />

            <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer4"
                />

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can not find where you changed the text color of the radio buttons. You changed the text color of your textview to white... Maybe you have a black bavkground with blavk text and black icons on it?

Comment: Try to change your main view background, maybe it have the same color as your text and RadioButton background.  This is why they look invisible for you.

Comment: i have tired changing background, the text is white on a black background, the text above in the textview displays fine but just the radio group is invisible

Comment: just tried and its the same problem

Comment: What does your **Run code snippet** button do?  It shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your radio buttons of radio group with this,

```
<RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 1"
            />

        <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 2"
            />

        <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 3"
            />

        <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 4"
            />
```

It will work :)

Comment: same problem unfortunatly :-( its a real puzzle, the radio group is supposed to display the answers from my database, they did do originally, i figured it cant be the database as the questions are showing fine! just the radiogroup invisible along with the answers

Comment: changed the text color after your edit to each button and the answers are displaying now but the radio buttons invisible

Comment: So the thumb of radio button inside radio group is not displaying right??

Comment: yea, its there because i press the screen and it appears as a green color and then vanishes again

Comment: its a selection check button if that helps

Comment: Hi i have added the same layout with static text and background.
And it was working fine means i can see question, answers and all the radio buttons.

Are you doing any design chagnes programetically?

Comment: hi, yes i was just looking into that and it seems i have 3 linear layouts on the activity! and have changed this now and the buttons do display, wouldnt of done it without your help though so thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: Where are you actually declaring a **RadioGroup**?? I don't see it in your code.